# Configure IBM WAS Liberty V8.5.5.6 & eXreme Scale

Tags: websphere-liberty, websphere-extreme-scale, ibm-wxs

I am attempting (and failing) to configure a development environment as follows:-

```
Eclipse 4.5 for Java EE Developers (Mars).
WebSphere Developer Tools
IBM WebSphere eXtreme Scale v8.5 Liberty Profile Developer Tools
WebSphere eXtreme Scale V8.6 for Developers - Liberty Profile
WAS Liberty V8.5.5.6 with Java EE 7 Full Platform
```

The issues I have relate to my organisations security constraints related to downloading resources from external web sites.

I can successfully configure the following separate environments

**eXtreme Scale**

```
Eclipse 4.5 for Java EE Developers (Mars).
WebSphere Developer Tools into Eclipse 
WebSphere eXtreme Scale V8.6 for Developers - Liberty Profile
WAS Liberty Beta v9 with OSGi Applications
```

**JEE7**

```
Eclipse 4.5 for Java EE Developers (Mars).
WebSphere Developer Tools into Eclipse 
WAS Liberty V8.5.5.6 with Java EE 7 Full Platform
```

My two blockers are

**Eclipse eXtreme Scale tools**

```
IBM WebSphere eXtreme Scale v8.5 Liberty Profile Developer Tools
```

Are only available as an Update Site. I can only install eclipse tools as zip archives.

Are these Eclipse tools available as a zip archive?

**OSGi Blueprint**
This feature is only installable using the command line

```
bin/installUtility install blueprint-1.0
```

Is this feature available as a jar download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About Eclipse eXtreme Scale tools.  You can get the zip version here,

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/extremescale/eclipse/localSite/localUpdateSite.zip

However, this tool will only work up to Eclipse Juno.  More information here,
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-extreme-scale-v86-liberty-profile-developer-tools

About OSGi Blueprint.  AFAIK, there is no zip version.  If there is a firewall issue, consider installing the required Liberty Runtime stack, zip it up and put it in the required machine.

btw, you may also need wab-1.0 as well as blueprint-1.0.  Here is the information,
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.websphere.appserver.wab-1.0

Hope it helps